# Android parse xml error - Root element name does not match

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

I want to parse an gpx (xml) document which starts as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1  http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" creator="Ian">
```

When parsing I get the follwoing error:

```
android.sax.BadXmlException: Line 1: Root element name does not match. Expected: 'gpx', Got: 'http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1:gpx'
```

However if I then remove the `xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"` attribute - it parses perfectly.

The code I'm using to parse is `android.util.Xml.parse(is,Xml.Encoding.UTF_8,gpx.getContentHandler());`

Does anyone know why this attribute is cauing the parse error?

Any help is much appreciated!
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your rootElement, you have an opportunity to specify the namespace...

> final RootElement rootElement = new RootElement("http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1", "gpx");

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid XML, I think you are just missing a `</gpx>` at the end or you can just self close it by doing `/>` at the end.

Comment: I don't think that is the OP's entire XML doc; it's just the first tag. (Based on the "*which starts as follows*" statement in the first sentence.)

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, but I am just showing part of the xml file. It is closed elsewhere and parses correctly if the xmlns attribute is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a namespace with the xmlns (so all your tag names will start with whatever you define in this attribute), which I guess the schema doesn't recognise.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't worked out how to resolve the problem, however if anyone else has the same issue, you can use a regexp to remove the xmlns attribute from the xml.

```
private static InputStream stripDeclaration(InputStream is) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String string = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    string = string.replaceFirst("xmlns=\".*?\"", "");
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes("UTF-8") );     
}
```

This isn't ideal as you need to create a string out of your enitre xml file which almost defeats the point of a sax parser. Any better ideas are very welcome!